# Is it possible to use list like array?

Tags: c++, list

I'd like to ask, Is it possible to make the list works like array?

I mean how to overload [] operator to make it work as in array.

I've read some kind of code. It's works for example when we want
-print memory cell : cout<<abc[0];

- left-hand assignment of a variable : b = abc[0];

but does't work right-hand : abc[0] = 5;
and I'dont know how to determine the size of the array

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>


using namespace std;

template<class type>
class My_array
{
    public:
    list<type> List;
    

    void add(type element)
    {
        List.push_back(element);
    }
    
    void dele()
    {
        List.pop_back();
    }
    
    type operator [](int i)
    {
        typename list<type>::iterator iter; 
        int counter = 0;
        
        for(iter = this->List.begin(); iter != this->List.end(); iter++)
        {
            if(counter == i) break;
            
            counter++;
        }
        
        
        return *iter;
        
    }
   
   My_array &operator = (My_array &k)
    {
        
        if(this == &k) return *this;
        
        
        return *this;
    }
    


};




int main()
{
    My_array<int> abc;
    abc.add(5);
    
    int b = 7;
    
    
    cout<<abc[0]<<endl;
    b = abc[0];
    cout<<b<<endl;
 
    
   
   
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even if it was possible, why do you want to specifically use list? Why not a vector?

Comment: FYI [`std::next()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) is useful to advance iterators.

Comment: It's (obviously, since your code demonstrates it) possible. Now *why has it not been done* for the existing standard list? Because it is inefficient. If you provide something like random access that looks simple people will use it and think it's simple. it isn't, and they shouldn't.

Comment: Because I learn about template and overloads and it good task

Comment: @kaniaramiawest Yes, it's a good exercise to write your own containers

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the overload to return a reference to the element.

```
    type& operator [](int i) // add & to make it return a reference
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change

```
type operator [](int i)
```

to

```
type& operator [](int i)
```

It works for access and assignment!